# Split text into multiple rows while creating/appending CSV or Excel file

Tags: python, excel, csv, pytest

I am able to create and append a CSV file from Python (pytest) in the below format.

[image]

I used below code to generate and append this file

```
user_list = col1.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "ul").text
total_count = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")[3].find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,
                                                                      'badge').text 

header = ['User Name', 'User count', 'Time']
data = [user_list,  total_count, time.strftime("%d%m%Y-%H%M%S")]

with open('users.csv', 'a', encoding='UTF8') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)

    # write the header
    writer.writerow(header)

    # write the data
    writer.writerow(data)
```

But I would like to split the texts in multiple rows while creating and appending CSV, i.e. in below format.

[image]

I tried couple of solutions but couldn't succeed, I am looking for some suggestions which work for CSV or in Excel.

Comment: If `user_list` looks like that just split it by `\n`, then iterate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a row for each user:

```
header = ['User Name', 'User count', 'Time']
#data = [user_list,  total_count, time.strftime("%d%m%Y-%H%M%S")]

with open('users.csv', 'a', encoding='UTF8') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)

    # write the header
    writer.writerow(header)

    # for each user
    for user in user_list:
        # create row
        rowdata = [user,  total_count, time.strftime("%d%m%Y-%H%M%S")]
        # write the data
        writer.writerow(rowdata)
```

I don't know what is in `user_list`. If it is not a list, but a string, then you probably have to split it:

```
for user in user_list.split():
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response it works with '''for user in user_list.split():'''